# Finding objects in an entanglement

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I'd like to know if there are ways to solve entanglement problems like this one:

[image]

Given a known shape (in red), can a machine locate (or at least count) the instances of this same object in an image containing multiple rotated and translated instances that are overlapping (in white)?

This is classical game that humans can do without too much difficulty, but from a machine vision point of view it seems quite a challenge.

The standard way to find instances in an image is to use feature detectors, but this approach is likely to fail here since 1) it seems pretty difficult to define features that are robust to overlapping and 2) one would need to group the found features into as many objects, which is also not trivial.

So, what approach could be used to solve this kind of problem?

NB: [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368226/finding-objects-in-an-image-given-a-single-instance-of-the-object-from-the-same) is related, but does not address the entanglement issue directly.